# Bitbucket API - Get list of comments on pull request inside merge hook

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

I am adding merge hook through bitbucket server plugin API to prevent merging of pull request if there is some specific comment is missing on PR

I am successfully able to apply this hook on PR, but DON'T see way to get list of comments on PR here

Here is my code snippet:

```
public class CodeReviewMergeCheck implements RepositoryMergeCheck {
    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public RepositoryHookResult preUpdate(@Nonnull PreRepositoryHookContext preRepositoryHookContext,
                                          @Nonnull PullRequestMergeHookRequest pullRequestMergeHookRequest) {
        pullRequestMergeHookRequest.getPullRequest().getTitle();
        **// I NEED LIST OF COMMENTS FROM PR HERE**
        return RepositoryHookResult.rejected("Code review pending", "Code review pending");
    }
}
```

How to get list of comments from PR here

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the full context however I don't agree with the implementation you are trying to achieve. You are searching for all comments in a PR and looking for a specific text. This can go wrong in many ways like,

1. What if there is a misspelling. You will allow the merge when it should not.
2. What about comment threads? If that text can be part of a thread.
3. A classic problem of searching a pattern when that pattern could be part of a bigger sentence. For example, "Code" vs "Coder"

There are better merge checks that you can use. For example,

1. Minimum number of reviewers
2. Incomplete task check - Create a task and if any of the tasks are not resolved, the merge is not allowed.

However, if you are still want to go through this, you can inject `CommentService` in your class and have something like following,

```
Page<Comment> comments = commentService.search(
                        new CommentSearchRequest.Builder(
                          pullRequestMergeHookRequest.getPullRequest()).build(), 
                        new PageRequestImpl(0, 1));
```

I strongly discourage going in this direction. It has the potential of making merge activity for user very sluggish.